# How can I revert yoda conditions with a PHP formatter in VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, formatter

So a long time ago I accidentally used a formatter that switched all my conditions to yoda and I only noticed the damage too late. Going back in time with the file history/git is not an option so I need a formatter extension that can revert them to normal, is there such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [php-cs-fixer VS Code extension](https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer) can revert them with the following configuration:

```
"php-cs-fixer.rules": {
    "yoda_style": {
        "equal": false,
        "identical": false,
        "less_and_greater": false
    }
},
```

[More info](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/doc/rules/control_structure/yoda_style.rst) about the yoda configuration.